# Run Github application on Windows

Tags: java, github, installation, yaml

I don't know how to make use of this application from GitHub. Or in other words, how to make use of it on Windows.

It is a Opensource Application that helps to convert Infobase files.

https://github.com/imazen/folioxml

**I am using Windows 10**

Answer (score 0):

The [build server](https://travis-ci.org/github/imazen/folioxml) for this project has been migrated and [gone offline](https://www.travis-ci.com/imazen/folioxml) so you cannot download a complete and compiled application jar.

If you are not familiar with code, then the easy answer is that you need to find someone who has compiled the jar file and has a link for you to download it (Be careful who you trust though), or try and contact the original author with the provided email address, but don't hold your breath for a 6y old project. I suggest looking for an alternate application/project.

---

### The longer/better answer:

Github is simply a location to share the projects source code. The home page has all the details you need on how to run the application: https://github.com/imazen/folioxml

Specifically, see the section about [running the command line](https://github.com/imazen/folioxml#running-the-command-line-app) app:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single -U -B -fae
java -jar commandline/target/folioxml-commandline-jar-with-dependencies.jar -config core/folioxml/resources/test.yaml -export folio_help
```

---

To complete the above you would first download a copy of the [source code](https://github.com/imazen/folioxml/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) and unzip it, or you could clone it using the github [command line](https://cli.github.com/) tools.

Then you would use the [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) console to run the clean and compile command:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single -U -B -fae
```

If there are any code issues you would need to fix them, and resolve any [dependency](https://github.com/imazen/folioxml#dependencies) issues. Once it has been compiled you can configure the YAML file as shown in the [Yaml configuration reference section](https://github.com/imazen/folioxml#yaml-configuration-reference).

Lastly, you can launch the application using the java command, although you will need to alter the command to point to the actual location of the compiled file, and the location of the YAML file. The example given is:

```
java -jar commandline/target/folioxml-commandline-jar-with-dependencies.jar -config core/folioxml/resources/test.yaml -export folio_help
```